# Cannot use Microsoft.VisualBasic As Reference

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Am trying to use Microsoft.VisualBasic, but I am using an intranet laptop and I cannot add reference from Visual Studio. Does anyone have any solution to get Namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic which has function like Dir(), DateDiff, CreateObject etc. (It is possible for me to download from the internet with another device and transfer it to the intranet laptop.)

Comment: Why can't you add the reference? In a VB.Net project, it's there by default. Do you mean, add the reference to a non-VB.Net project? Are you sure you can't see it in `Project->References->Add reference` or in the Project properties/references?

Comment: The thing is that normally the Microsoft.VisualBasic Namespace should be in the metadata but I am not sure why it isn't there in my intranet laptop.

Comment: So, you have an error notification in `Application.Designer.vb`, `Settings.Designer.vb` etc. where the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly is of course referenced otherwise nothing works?

Comment: I would say that it cant be reference because it isn' there in the first place XD. So my question is what is an alternative method I can do to get Microsoft.VisualBasic As a reference, other than right click my solution and add reference as it would not work for an intranet device.

Comment: No idea what an *intranet device* is of what the Intranet has to do with it. That assembly is installed in the local machine along with Visual Studio.

Comment: As it is an intranet device, I believe the installer for visual studios does not contain all the files needed, thus leading to many files to be missing. Like I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and I have to find it from the interent and transfer to my Intranet computer.

Comment: You don't need the Microsoft.VisualBasic library; all functions have equivalents in the .NET Framework (presuming you have that transferred to your 'intranet').

Comment: By "intranet laptop," do you mean a computer which cannot be connected to the internet? Did you create a DVD of the Visual Studio installer, such that you could repair the Visual Studio installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a VisualBasic project, the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly is already referred.

If you are in a C# project and like to use Visual Basic functionality (what I guess you might mean - sorry but your question is not *too* precise in that aspect), you have to reference it manually. It should be found in the "Assemblies" tab when you click on "Add Reference...", but you can also find it in your `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` resp. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` folders.

As C# does not allow to omit the module name, you have to prefix your function with it, e.g. `DateAndTime.DateDiff(..)` (after having the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic imported with a `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`).

But my recommendation is: Use .NET instead of VB6 compatibility methods whereever possible. I personally only use Microsoft.VisualBasic from C# to use the `LIKE` operator.